# Angular deactivate compilation on any element

Tags: angularjs, compilation

I want to use a textarea to write angular templates, how can I stop the compile on this textarea tag.

Because the submitted value is compiled when I refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `ng-non-bindable` for example:

```
<textarea name="context" ng-non-bindable="" id="context" ng-model="model.context" >
    <div ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="myGrid">
</textarea>
```